# How to use jquery/javascript replace as preg_replace in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The preg_replace function in PHP provides  a limit parameter. For instance, the first occurrence of medium replace with original, and the second occurrence of medium replace with "type".

```
$path = "demo\/medium\/Web081112_P001_medium.jpg";
$path = preg_replace ("/medium/","original",$path,1);
$path = preg_replace ("/medium/","type",$path,2);
echo $path;
// output : demo\/original\/Web081112_P001_type.jpg
```

So, are there any way using JQuery/ JavaScript to implement similar function? Thanks

Comment: That `2` doesn't do what you think it does... the first occurrence has already been replaced by that time.

Comment: You don't use jQuery for string manipulation. [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is a much better choice.

Comment: @nnnnnn: OMG, haven't seen that link yet, that's hilarious! :D

Comment: @Amadan - Yes, it's awesome. Did you notice you can select the features you want and download a custom JS include file? I think the site's only been around since the middle of this year - I'd love to know if somebody on SO is responsible; they should get a one-off platinum JS badge for it or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any way using jquery/ javascript to implement similar function?

Use JavaScript's native [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

By default, `replace()` will only replace the first occurrence - unless you set the `g` modifier.

#### Example:

```
path = "demo/medium/Web081112_P001_medium.jpg";
path = path.replace("/medium/", "original");
path = path.replace("medium", "type");
```

**Note:** Your code doesn't match your specification. I addressed your specification.

Answer (score 4):

General solution:

```
var n = 0;
"a a a a a".replace(/a/g, function(match) {
  n++;
  if (n == 2) return "c";
  if (n == 3 || n == 4) return "b";
  return match;
})
// => "a c b b a"
```

Also, you are mistaken: the second replacement will not happen. Limit 2 doesn't say "second occurence", it says "two occurences"; however, after the first `preg_replace` you don't have two mediums any more, so the second `preg_replace` ends up replacing the single one that is left, and then quits in frustration. You could do the same using two single-shot (non-global) `replace` (or `preg_replace`) invocations, without using any limit.

Comment: Seems like quite the long way around.

Comment: Cool, solution works! JavaScript is so unexpected and funny :)